# Uploading images to Postgres with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, image, postgresql, sinatra

So, I'm trying to make a little image posting blog, kinda of like tumblr but just for images of The Simpsons (it's for class).

I am trying to do a straight upload with Sinatra to the Postgres database, and I can get a connection and it adds the content in, but adds every single detail, not just the image. 
I get this junk:

```
"image/png", :name=>"file", :tempfile=>#, :head=>"Content-  Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"Homer_Simpson_4.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n"}" alt="">
```

where the image should be shown.

I'm thinking it has something to do with converting the image to make it readable. Binary data? I want just the image stored on the db, and maybe rename it so something easy to save.

This is the upload route I have

```
post '/upload' do
@post = Post.new

@post.content = params[:file]
@post.user_id = current_user.id
@post.save

unless params[:file] &&
     (tmpfile = params[:file][:tempfile]) &&
     (name = params[:file][:filename])
@error = "No file selected"
return erb :submit
end
STDERR.puts "Uploading file, original name #{name.inspect}"
while blk = tmpfile.read(65536)
# here you would write it to its final location
STDERR.puts blk.inspect
end
"Upload complete"
redirect to '/'
end
```

I got this code from the ruby-forum and it does everything that i thought it would, and pops me back, even does some storage.

and this is the form I have:

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="">Upload an Image</label>
<input type="file" name="file" />
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

I have a Model for the post database (active record) and the columns are just the id of the post, the content and the user_id of the poster.

I've never tried any sort of uploader before, so I'm very confused about how the file uploads stores. Do I need a new column for the image? Or maybe a table?

Sorry if this is a trainwreck of a question, I'm trying to work on my Stack Overflow capabilities (turns out it's a very important part of development, along with Googling).

Comment: Not a solution, but i would encourage you to look at either a file system store or saving the data in S3.  You can rack up Gigabytes of image data pretty quick and your cost of managing that on postgres binary are probably going to be way higher than just a flat disk or s3.  If you do that, you store the reference to the file in your table and then read from there.  Look at Refile gem for examples on how they implement.

Comment: I'll go check out file system storage I think. Could I use it with heroku? The app needs to be deployed to heroku to be run, do they allow a system like that?

Comment: No, you will have to cloud storage like S3.  Their file system is ephemeral.  https://github.com/refile/refile carrier wave also has an easy upload to s3 but requires more configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You really should look at [refile](https://github.com/refile/refile) or [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) both were written by an excellent developer and make the job really easy. Really, don't try to store in the database and you definitely cannot store on Heroku.

Comment: Got two recommendations for refile. Checking that one out first. Thank! A quick question, what would the uploader that I'm using at the moment typically be used for? Small text files?

Comment: Yes, I'd probably only use it for simple things like uploading a csv or similar that you are going to parse immediately and never store.